# How can I add a drop down list in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-table

Following situation:

I'm programming a web-app, which get data from a server. I want to put these data in an table with two columns. In the first column there should be a name and in the second column should be a drop down list to choose which detailed information I want to get about the name in the first column.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="datajs-1.0.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
function readCustomerSuccessCallback(data, response) {

     var customerTable = document.getElementById("CustomerTable");
     for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var row = customerTable.insertRow(1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1 = "data.results[i].CUSTOMER_NAME";
            cell2.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="readProducts(' + data.results[i].STATION_ID + ')">' + data.results[i].CUSTOMER_NAME + '</a>';

        }
    }
</head>
<body> 

<table id="CustomerTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Filter the Data</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>EXAMPLE</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                 <form action="" name="FILTER">
                     <select name="filter_for" size="5">
                         <option value="Druck">Druck</option>
                         <option value="Zahl">Zahl</option>
                         <option value="Temperatur">Temperatur</option>
                         <option value="Drehzahl">Drehzahl</option>
                         <option value="andere">andere</option>
                     </select>
                 </form>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My Problem is, that the function does not create the drop down list in the second column. I'm new with html and Javascript and searching in the web didn't help.

Comment: What function? I don't see any function to create the drop down menu. You are also missing a closing tag `</script>` and have an unfinished body tag `<body`.

Comment: my code are more thann 400 lines long, because I have also many other functions. I'm sorry for miss these two. In my code they are correct

Comment: I tried many things out. Has anybody an idea how I can fill the cell2 with the drop down menu? I think this is my main problem

Comment: If you want help with a function that creates a dropdown into a table cell, you will need to include that function into the question. Or is that what `readCustomerSuccessCallback` is supposed to be doing? Because it just adds table rows, where the second column is a link that calls a function on click.

Comment: Such as you said. the table is created in the <body> and the funktion readCustomerSuccessCallback ad for each Customer one row. In each row should be in the first column the name, and ich the second a drop down list. Its quite difficult to let the function this do

Comment: You should put dropdown HTML code into the second column instead of a link. And for your first column it should be `cell1.textContent = data.results[i].CUSTOMER_NAME;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
<body 

<table id="CustomerTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Filter the Data</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>EXAMPLE</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                 <form action="" name="FILTER">
                     <select name="filter_for" >
                         <option value="Druck">Druck</option>
                         <option value="Zahl">Zahl</option>
                         <option value="Temperatur">Temperatur</option>
                         <option value="Drehzahl">Drehzahl</option>
                         <option value="andere">andere</option>
                     </select>
                 </form>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/unyswphc/)

Answer (score 1):

Just open the form before the table opens, and close the form after the  tag.

Just like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="datajs-1.0.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
function readCustomerSuccessCallback(data, response) {

     var customerTable = document.getElementById("CustomerTable");
     for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var row = customerTable.insertRow(1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1 = "data.results[i].CUSTOMER_NAME";
            cell2.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="readProducts(' + data.results[i].STATION_ID + ')">' + data.results[i].CUSTOMER_NAME + '</a>';

        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="FILTER">
<table id="CustomerTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Filter the Data</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>EXAMPLE</td>
             <td class="dropdown">

                     <select name="filter_for" size="5">
                         <option value="Druck">Druck</option>
                         <option value="Zahl">Zahl</option>
                         <option value="Temperatur">Temperatur</option>
                         <option value="Drehzahl">Drehzahl</option>
                         <option value="andere">andere</option>
                     </select>

             </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just edit the original answer. Don't keep the old one and add the fixed one. It's confusing.

Comment: What does it means when the table is part of the form?

Comment: The table isn't a part of the form, only inputs are part of the form. That the table tags are between the form tags doesn't mean they belong to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `body` element with a `>` so it looks like this: `<body>`. That's all you need.

Also, if you want it to be an actual dropdown (right now it's a selectbox), remove the `size` attribute from the `select` tag.

```html
<body>

<table id="CustomerTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Filter the Data</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>EXAMPLE</td>
             <td class="dropdown">
                 <form action="" name="FILTER">
                     <select name="filter_for" size="5">
                         <option value="Druck">Druck</option>
                         <option value="Zahl">Zahl</option>
                         <option value="Temperatur">Temperatur</option>
                         <option value="Drehzahl">Drehzahl</option>
                         <option value="andere">andere</option>
                     </select>
                 </form>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: what du you mean with an "actual dropdown"?

Comment: Your example isn't a dropdown. The `size` attribute allows viewing the options all at once. A dropdown only displays the current value, and you click it to display the other available options. See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/cVfaY5EDWsmlz9EBHNi2?p=preview